# Read buffer object in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to get html page through this node module called [Wreck](https://www.npmjs.org/package/wreck)

It should be very easy to get data but I'm unable to get them

```
'use strict';

var Wreck = require('wreck');

var url = 'http://www.google.it';

var callback = function(err, response, payload){
  Wreck.read(response, null, function(err, body){
      //here print out the html page
  });
};

Wreck.get(url, callback);
```

Here above a simple script just a copy from the readme of the developer. according to the documentation `body` should return a buffer object but how can I read inside a body object? I have read to use toJSON or toString() but I don't get any result

Comment: Can you show us what exact code you did use in the `read` callback, and what it printed? Did an error happen?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ...but I don't get any result

You ARE getting a result, an empty `Buffer`, but it's not want you want, probably.

The fact is: you are using the `read` method wrong, passing it inside a callback to the `get` method. The methods `get`, `post`, `put` and `delete` already call `read` internaly and return the readable `Buffer` for you, in a callback. Take a look at the `get` [doc](https://github.com/hapijs/wreck#geturi-options-callback):

> **get(uri, [options], callback)**
>
> Convenience method for GET operations.
>
> - uri - The URI of the requested resource.
> - options - Optional config object containing settings for both request and read operations.
> - callback - The callback function using the signature function (err, response, payload) where:
>
>   - err - Any error that may have occurred during handling of the request.
>   - response - The HTTP Incoming Message object, which is also a readable stream.
>   - payload - The payload in the form of a Buffer or (optionally) parsed JavaScript object (JSON).

So, the use of the `get` method is pretty straightforward (using your own example):

```
var callback = function(err, response, payload){
  console.log(payload.toString()); // converting the buffer to a string and logging
};

Wreck.get(url, callback);
```